Do I need to create a configuration file for router in OpenVPN?
In documentation it is not clear do I need to create a configuration file or I just need to check it?
It is not the duplicate because here I am asking if I need to create my, not to find.
The configuring of OpenVPN included only using this command bash <(curl -fsS https://as-repository.openvpn.net/as/install.sh

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

The script you mentioned installs the Access Server, but you still need a custom config file to specify how your OpenVPN client should connect to the server. This file will include details like server IP, certificates, and other settings required to establish the connection.

So how to create it?

@NikolaiVorobiev Your question was whether it was needed. lostmarien has answered that question. Please use the checkmark icon to mark it as an answer. If you have further questions ask them as new questions.

@music2myear, Ok

@music2myear and iostmarien, Ok, thank you, I asked a new question(it was even before it), but nobody answered
